# Convert Birthdate to Getdate

Tags: marketing-cloud, date, sql, automationstudio

I am trying to send a message to everyone whose birthdate is in two weeks but the date is of a different format and the query thus returns 0 rows.

The query I am currently using is the following

```
SELECT FirstName, PersonEmail AS EmailAddress, Id AS SubscriberKey, Language__c AS Language
FROM ent.[Account_Salesforce_1] 
WHERE PersonBirthdate = DATEADD(day, 14, cast(GetDate() AS date))
AND FirstName IS NOT NULL
AND PersonEmail IS NOT NULL
AND Id IS NOT NULL
AND Language__c IS NOT NULL
```

The format that has been passed from Service Cloud is the following:
Thursday, December 13, 1984 12:00 AM

To what type do I need to change the format in order to make this work?

Comment: Can you remove the cast function and give it a try? If the PersonBirthdate is a date field in sync DE, it doesn't require CAST to compare.

Comment: I just realized I am trying to compare a current date against a date from 1984... How can I focus on just the month and day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two remarks:

- you also compare the year, which will never evaluate to true.
- you don’t observe the system time zone (UTC-6) which in some cases can cause issues, as the date of birth is normally provided in local time zone

Here is a sample SQL overcoming both issues:

```
select * from anywhere 
WHERE 
datepart(day, [Date of birth]) = 
datepart(day,SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() 
AT TIME ZONE 'Central European Standard Time')
AND 
datepart(month, [Date of birth]) = 
datepart(month,SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() 
AT TIME ZONE 'Central European Standard Time’)
```